# In PHP, how to reference a class in another class' static variable

Tags: php, unit-testing

When working with static classes / methods in PHP, I am not sure how to do the following. This code will not run, but should give you an idea of what I want to do.

```
class Accounts {
   static public $emailer = Site_Emailer;
   static function add( $id ) {
       self::$emailer::send( 'New account created' );
   }
}
```

Then in a Unit Test, I want to test that calling this method will send an email:

```
function testAccountsAddEmails() {

    Accounts::$email = Mock_Emailer;
    Accounts::add( 1 );

    $this->assertTrue( count( Mock_Emailer::$sent ) === 1 );
}
```

The issue I am running into is the static variable of Accounts `$emailer` can not just hold the Class, I could have it hold a string of the class name, then use `call_user_func()` but that seems somewhat messy.

I hope that clarifies the issue I am having, let me know if more notes required!

Thanks

Comment: Is it correct that your question basically is: "How to store an object in a static variable in PHP?"

Comment: WHY do they have to be static? But I like that you try to unit test. It's like making sure that a broken engine is reliable

Comment: @Frog No, I wanted to reference a Class, not at Object

Comment: @MikeSW Good question, I guess I could use a singleton approach for this too right?

Comment: Why do you need a single instance for this class? Use static ONLY when you have a very good reason to.

Comment: @MikeSW becuase there will only ever be one instance of Accounts, sense why I originally used static. If Accounts is "setup" on the script init, I was thinking a singleton is the easiest way to get a hand on that single and only instance from anywhere

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
class Accounts {
   static public $emailer = 'Site_Emailer'; // String representation of class name
   static function add( $id ) {
       call_user_func(
           array(self::$emailer, 'send'),
           'New account created' 
       );
   }
}
```

Similarly, you have to use string while assigning it to variable in your test case:

```
Accounts::$email = 'Mock_Emailer`;
```

But consider using real objects and dependency injection.

Comment: Ok that makes sense, as I had "Accounts" being essentially one-copy, is a singleton a valid approach in that case?